# Get section title and table on same page

Tags: tables

I have a problem with getting a section title and a table on the same page since I want the text in my table centered. Is there a way around this? Thank you!

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}

\subsection{Theoretically Calculated Disulfide-Bound Fragment Masses}

\begin{table*}
    \hspace*{-1.5cm}
     \caption{\textit{Theoretically calculated molecular weights of trypsin-cleaved disulfide bonded fragments of LECT2 that were searched for in the MS spectra.}}
    \vspace{2mm}
        \begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
        \vspace{3mm}
         & & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{TCDR}\\ \textbf{(Cys 36)}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{GFCVK}\\ \textbf{(Cys 99)}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{HGCGQ} \\ \textbf{YSAQR}\\  \textbf{(Cys 41)}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{HHHENL} \\ \textbf{YFQGPW}\\ \textbf{ANICAGK}\\ \textbf{(Cys 25)}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{VYPGIQSHV} \\ \textbf{HIENCDSSD} \\ \textbf{PTAYL} \\    \textbf{(Cys 142)}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{SQRPHQGVD} \\ \textbf{ILCSAGSTV} \\ \textbf{YAPFTGMIV} \\ \textbf{GQEKPYQNK}\\ \textbf{(Cys 60)}\end{tabular} \\
        \vspace{3mm}
        &  & {\color[HTML]{A9A9A9} 494.203} & {\color[HTML]{A9A9A9} 553.28}  & {\color[HTML]{A9A9A9} 1106.48}  & {\color[HTML]{A9A9A9} 2222.03}  & {\color[HTML]{A9A9A9} 2545.17} & {\color[HTML]{A9A9A9} 3906.93} \\
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{TCDR}\\ \textbf{(Cys 36)}\end{tabular} & {\color[HTML]{A9A9A9} 494.203} & 986.3898 & & & & &  \\
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{GFCVK}\\ \textbf{(Cys 99)} \end{tabular} & {\color[HTML]{A9A9A9} 553.28}  & 1045.467  & 1104.545  &  &   &    & \\
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{HGCGQ} \\ \textbf{YSAQR} \\      \textbf{(Cys 41)}\end{tabular} & {\color[HTML]{A9A9A9} 1106.48} & {\color[HTML]{333388} \textbf{1598.667}} & {\color[HTML]{A9A9A9} 1657.744} & 2210.943 & & & \\
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{HHHENL} \\ \textbf{YFQGPW} \\ \textbf{ANICAGK} \\ \textbf{(Cys 25)} \end{tabular} & {\color[HTML]{A9A9A9} 2222.03} & 2714.222 & 2773.299 & 3326.499 & 4442.054  & & \\
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{VYPGIQSHV} \\ \textbf{HIENCDSSD} \\ \textbf{PTAYL}\\ \textbf{(Cys142)}\end{tabular} & {\color[HTML]{A9A9A9} 2545.17} & 3037.353 & {\color[HTML]{FF0000} \textbf{\large{3096.431}}} & 3649.63 & 4765.186 & 5088.317 &  \\
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{SQRPHQGVD} \\ \textbf{ILCSAGSTV} \\ \textbf{YAPFTGMIV} \\ \textbf{GQEKPYQNK}\\  \textbf{(Cys  60)}\end{tabular} & {\color[HTML]{A9A9A9} 3906.93} & 4399.114 & 4458.191 & 5011.39  & {\color[HTML]{333388} \textbf{6126.946}} & 6450.077 & 7811.837 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: Do you use the default margins?

Comment: No I use \usepackage[hmargin=20mm,top=18mm,columnsep=15pt]{geometry}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a table (or figure) page wide in the same otherwise two-column page, *after* the section title, you can use the `strip` environment, from the `cuted` package. This makes your table non-float, so for the caption, you have to use the `\captionof{table}{...}`  command.

Here is a possible solution, with some simplifications and improvements, with the `siunitx` and `makecell` packages.

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=20mm,top=18mm,columnsep=15pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell, caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}
\usepackage{cuted}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Theoretically Calculated Di\-sul\-fide-Bound Fragment Masses}
\mbox{}
\begin{strip}
\small\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\captionsetup{textfont = it}
\sisetup{table-format=4.3, table-number-alignment=center}
 \captionof{table}{Theoretically calculated molecular weights of trypsin-cleaved disulfide bonded fragments of LECT2 that were searched for in the MS spectra.}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}c>{\color{DarkGray}}SS[table-format=4.4]*{6}{S}@{}}
         & &{\thead{\\\\\\TCDR\\ (Cys 36)}} &{\thead{\\\\\\GFCVK \\ (Cys 99)}} &{ \thead{\\\\HGCGQ \\ YSAQR \\ (Cys 41)}} & {\thead{\\HHHENL \\ YFQGPW \\ ANICAGK \\ (Cys 25)}} & {\thead{\\VYPGIQSHV \\ HIENCDSSD \\ PTAYL \\ (Cys 142)}} & {\thead{SQRPHQGVD \\ ILCSAGSTV \\ YAPFTGMIV \\ GQEKPYQNK \\ (Cys 60)}} \\[2ex]
        & & \color{DarkGray} 494.203 & \color{DarkGray} 553.28 & \color{DarkGray} 1106.48 & \color{DarkGray} 2222.03 & \color{DarkGray} 2545.17 & \color{DarkGray} 3906.93 \\[2ex]
        \thead{TCDR \\ (Cys 36)} & 494.203 & 986.3898 & & & & & \\[2ex]
        \thead{GFCVK \\ (Cys 99)} & 553.28 & 1045.467 & 1104.545 & & & & \\[2ex]
        \thead{HGCGQ \\ YSAQR \\ (Cys 41)} & 1106.48 & \color[HTML]{333388} \textbf{1598.667} & \color{DarkGray} 1657.744 & 2210.943 & & & \\[2ex]
        \thead{HHHENL \\ YFQGPW \\ ANICAGK \\ (Cys 25)} & 2222.03 & 2714.222 & 2773.299 & 3326.499 & 4442.054 & & \\[2ex]
        \thead{VYPGIQSHV \\ HIENCDSSD \\ PTAYL \\ (Cys142)} & 2545.17 & 3037.353 & \color[HTML]{FF0000} \textbf{\normalsize{3096.431}} & 3649.63 & 4765.186 & 5088.317 & \\
        \thead{SQRPHQGVD \\ ILCSAGSTV \\ YAPFTGMIV \\ GQEKPYQNK \\(Cys 60)} & 3906.93 & 4399.114 & 4458.191 & 5011.39 & \color[HTML]{333388} \textbf{6126.946} & 6450.077 & 7811.837
    \end{tabular}
\end{strip}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following is a slight modification of [Bernards previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/508453/134144).

Maybe you are interested in slightly changing the layout of your table in order to make it more compact. Like this, the table will easily fit into the textwidth without decreasing the font size or the tabcolsep:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=20mm,top=18mm,columnsep=15pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell, caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\bfseries
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}
\usepackage{cuted}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Theoretically Calculated Di\-sul\-fide-Bound Fragment Masses}
\mbox{}
\begin{strip}
%\small
\centering
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\captionsetup{textfont = it}
\sisetup{table-format=4.3, table-number-alignment=center, detect-weight=true}
\captionof{table}{Theoretically calculated molecular weights of trypsin-cleaved disulfide bonded fragments of LECT2 that were searched for in the MS spectra.}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l>{\color{DarkGray}}*{8}{S}@{}}
         & &{\thead{Cys 36}} &{\thead{Cys 99}} &{ \thead{Cys 41}} & {\thead{Cys 25}} & {\thead{Cys 142}} & {\thead{Cys 60}} \\
        & & \color{DarkGray} 494.203 & \color{DarkGray} 553.28 & \color{DarkGray} 1106.48 & \color{DarkGray} 2222.03 & \color{DarkGray} 2545.17 & \color{DarkGray} 3906.93 \\
        \thead{Cys 36} & 494.203 & 986.3898 & & & & & \\
        \thead{Cys 99} & 553.28 & 1045.467 & 1104.545 & & & & \\
        \thead{Cys 41} & 1106.48 & \bfseries \color[HTML]{333388} 1598.667 & \color{DarkGray} 1657.744 & 2210.943 & & & \\
        \thead{Cys 25} & 2222.03 & 2714.222 & 2773.299 & 3326.499 & 4442.054 & & \\
        \thead{Cys142} & 2545.17 & 3037.353 & \bfseries \color[HTML]{FF0000} 3096.431 & 3649.63 & 4765.186 & 5088.317 & \\
        \thead{Cys 60} & 3906.93 & 4399.114 & 4458.191 & 5011.39 & \bfseries \color[HTML]{333388} 6126.946 & 6450.077 & 7811.837\\[2ex]
        \multicolumn{8}{@{}l@{}}{Cys 36: TCDR, Cys 99: GFCVK, Cys 41: HGCGQYSAQR,}\\
        \multicolumn{8}{@{}l@{}}{Cys 25: HHHENLYFQGPWANICAGK, Cys 142: VYPGIQSHVHIENCDSSDPTAYL,}\\
        \multicolumn{8}{@{}l@{}}{Cys 60: SQRPHQGVDILCSAGSTVYAPFTGMIVGQEKPYQNK} 
    \end{tabular}
\end{strip}

\end{document}
```